# LLVM: Segfault when accessing to function's argument

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, llvm

Here's my code ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15bc8b2bc335a662)):

```
#include <memory>

#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
int main()
{
    using namespace llvm;

    LLVMContext context;
    IRBuilder<> builder{context};
    std::unique_ptr<Module> module{std::make_unique<Module>("anon", context)};

    FunctionType* fnType{FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(context), {Type::getDoubleTy(context)}, false)};
    Function* fn{Function::Create(fnType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "fn", module.get())};

    fn->arg_begin()->setName("test");

    module->dump();
}
```

There is a segfault, but when I comment out the line 17 (where I accede to my argument), all works perfectly.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000508032 in getSymTab(llvm::Value*, llvm::ValueSymbolTable*&) ()
#0  0x0000000000508032 in getSymTab(llvm::Value*, llvm::ValueSymbolTable*&) ()
#1  0x0000000000509ae5 in llvm::Value::setNameImpl(llvm::Twine const&) ()
#2  0x0000000000509ca9 in llvm::Value::setName(llvm::Twine const&) ()
#3  0x0000000000405bf0 in main ()
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Most likely a LLVM bug. I'm unable to reproduce with LLVM 3.9.1. However, Valgrind shows an invalid read in `DataLayout (DataLayout.h:182)` called by `llvm::Module::Module(llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&) (Module.cpp:52)` on my system.

Comment: So, this bug is corrected on the latest version of LLVM? When I'll try on my computer, it will works?